# iPhone Saving Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a custom cell with a thumbnail image, which the user can select from their photo albums.  I know that saving images to Core Data will result in poor performance, and I should use the file system.

Anyone recommend some good tutorials on this.  What exactly should I store in core data, if I am not storing the image there.

I will be storing the larger image as well, not just the thumbnail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIImage*image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"the image you wish to save.jpg"];

//build the path for your image on the filesystem
NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* photoName = @"imageName.jpg";
NSString *photoPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];

//get the imageData from your UIImage
float imageCompression = 0.5;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, imageCompression);

//save the image                  
if(![imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES]){
    return FALSE;
}

//store the imagePath to your model
photoModal.filePathImage = photoPath;
```

TIPS:

- Avoid duplicate names so you don't override exisitng files (don't worry you'll get a warning)
- Remember to delete the photo when the model is being deleted
- Build a logical path and folder structure that matches your model, e.g - album.photo should have a folder named album and in it you should store the files, helps when you delete the album model

Comment: any recommendations on avoiding duplicate image names, make them unique

Comment: The best way i found is by adding in a persistent location like a globalApp model or NSUserDefaults a counter for a how many photos were ever created, you can then just add this number to each file name.

Comment: second option is generating a unique id for each photos but those are messy and bad looking...

Answer (score 2):

You should have two fields in your core data db : `thumbnailPath` : `NSString` and `originalPath` : `NSString`

With the file manager you create your thumbnail and original image at a specific path. so you'll have : ..../thumbs/myPicture_thumb.jpg  AND ..../originals/myPicture.jpg
Then you just store this two path to your core data db.

When you wan to display one of them you juste use `UIImage` method : [imageWithContentsOfFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

That's all

Answer (score 1):

You can store the Images in the `Application Documents Folder` and save the path of the Images in CoreData or sqlite. Refer the Images with their paths.